# Explicit SQL Pass through SQL Query in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to display from the Oracle table the latest day from each particular month and I am facing a issue with the right function. I am trying like below, but it doesn't work.

```
proc sql;
connect to Oracle( );
create table work.database as 
select * from connection to Oracle
(select * from  oracle_table_name
where column_name= intnx('month',column_name, -1,'E');
disconnect from Oracle;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here (beyond some typos) is that you are using `intnx`, a SAS function, in pass-through SQL.

Pass-through SQL means you are submitting Oracle SQL code directly to Oracle and saying "please run this".  You need to use the proper Oracle date functions in the `where` clause.